# How can the cards fill the entire width of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to create a recyclerview of cards. I get the information from the firebase realtime database but cards didn't fill the width of screen.

find_tournament.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3E2743"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FindTournamentActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tournamentImageParticipant"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tournamentLabelParticipant"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
            android:text="Tournament Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/jitrino"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Desing view of find tournament:
[find_tournament.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nGTU.png)

tournament_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#4F2A36"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tournamentImageRow"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tournamentNameRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tournament Name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tournamentGameRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tournament Game"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tournamentRewardRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reward"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
         </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tournamentPersonRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="N"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Vs"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tournamentPerson2Row"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="N"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Desing view of tournament row:
[tournament_row.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spx35.png)

Here is the result when i run the app. How can i fill gaps?
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOuuR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:elevation="20dp"
  app:cardBackgroundColor="#4F2A36"
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/tournamentImageRow"
          android:layout_width="80dp"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tournamentImageRow"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/end"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tournamentNameRow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Tournament Name"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tournamentGameRow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Tournament Game"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tournamentRewardRow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Reward"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/end"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/tournamentImageRow"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tournamentImageRow"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tournamentPersonRow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="N"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="Vs"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />
            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tournamentPerson2Row"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="N"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of the LinearLayout below the image is wrap_content. You can go around this problem by using weight.
Refer to this link for more information about weight
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2016/06/android-understanding-linearlayout.html

Please note that it is recommended to use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: `Please note that it is recommended to use ConstraintLayout.` why ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody It makes it easier to make a complex design and has better performance. Check the link for more information [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html)

Comment: i'm not asking for myself, i'm saying this is information you should _add_ to your answer as it's something people will ask :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you for the info. I have been a developer for more than 3 years now and I almost never contributed. I will make sure my answers will be more informative next time. :)

Comment: that's all good, writing a _good_ answer takes some practice, because even if there's something you know or understand, you have to write in a way others will understand, too